# Samsung tablet locked with power on

Tags: samsung

my daughter has forgotten the password for her tablet. Not an issue if the device was off but it is on. Any suggestions?

Comment: whats the matter of "with power on" (what exactly is your question targeting)? Do you want to know how to switch off? Or do you asking for hacking the password?

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the device will do the job. But you'll lose all your data. There's also a risk of google account authentication requirement on reboot after you format in certain devices involved so continue at your own risk.
Here's how to do it:

1. Press and hold the power button for 8 seconds, and the device will power off automatically.
2. Reboot the device by pressing and holding <kbd>Volume down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> button at the same time
3. Now, you can format your device from the recovery mode. Navigate with the volume keys and choose wipe data/factory reset. Press the power button to confirm.
4. Your device will reboot after formatting just like a new device and logging in back to your Google account will restore most of the data if you had backed up before.

Comment: 4. Is not correct, it is not "just like a new device" This will trigger FRP lock on modern Samsung devices. You should clearly WARN that the previous used google account is still bonded to the device, and without knowing the google account and password, the device becomes unusable

Comment: I did it on my mom's new Samsung J8 infinity (android pie v9.something, approx 1 month ago) after she forgot her pin, and it worked just fine. No google authentication was required, even though she had her google account in the phone before. So not all modern Samsung devices for sure have this much security.

Comment: the Samsung J8 definitely has FRP (i guess the only possible reason can be, there was no google account bonded at time of reset) regardless please add a warning, i cannot technically revoke my downvote until you edit your answer

Comment: There were google accounts in the J8, infact there was two, one being work and other personal. Anyways as you've said it,I made the edit. After all the person hasn't mentioned the device model so no guarantees ig.

Comment: then someone must have already OEM unlock allowed in developer settings (previous owner?)